# Cut and paste specific data from one column to another

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I need help in executing following:

on sheet 1 :

Column 'A' has 1000 lines of data like example below:

```
A
Hello  ABC 123456
Hi     ABC 98765
Hey    ABC 46892
:
:
:
:
HRU   ABC 73028

and so on...
```

Now I wanted to cut and paste specific data from Column A and paste it in Column B. Like Data to cut is from "ABC Numbers" and paste in Column 'B'

Here's what I getting trouble I am able to cut and paste complete data from A to B but is there some script that i can use to cut and paste only specific data?

Always Column "A" data to cut is from "ABC Numbers" here ABC is common for all the 1000's of rows

Comment: I would suggest an if loop.

Comment: Have you tried using `Text-To-Column` (with a fixed width it seems)? Of course this would also copy Hey, Hi, Hello, etc. over but then you'd merely have to delete column `B` and you should have what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use MID and FIND:

```
=MID(A1,FIND("ABC",A1),LEN(A1))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

use `Replace()` method of `Range` object:

```
Range("A1", Cells(Rows.Count,1).End(xlUp)).Replace "*ABC", "ABC", xlPart
```